# Select row if conditions is greater than 100

Tags: mysql

I have two table in my database, 
- `user`
- `videos`

In my `user` table I have a column called `balance` and in my `videos` I have I column called `views`.

I want if the views in my video reach 1000 my balance will update by plus one in my user table any ideas.

```
SELECT view
FROM videos
If views=1000
    UPDATE user SET balance=balance+1 WHERE user
id = user id
```

Comment: The tables are unrelated? There are multiple users in the users table and multiple videos in the videos table (each video with a number of views), but neither the videos nor the views have anything to do with particular users?

Comment: The video have user id that uploaded the video, if any video user upload get 1000 views let the user balance update plus 1

Comment: You need a trigger. google it

Comment: I'm with Ankit Bajpai here; you probably want to automatically increase a balance when a user's video rewaches 1000 views. That's done with database triggers.

Comment: If two videos user have 1000 views the balance should be +1, the balance keep plusing by 1000 views  each video has, like 1000 +1,2000 +1 3000 +1 it will keep on plusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an update-join statement:

```
UPDATE user u
JOIN   views v ON u.userid = v.userid
SET    balance = balance + 1
WHERE  v.views >= 1000
```